# Mcollective Chef service agent failed to run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, mcollective

I have configure `mcollective` and install following `service` agent to `start/stop` service

https://github.com/rottenbytes/mcollective/blob/master/plugins/agents/chef-service.rb

But when i running it, its failing at `client.build_node` and i am seeing error `undefined method reset_defaults_and_overrides for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

```
require 'chef'
require 'chef/client'
require 'chef/run_context'
begin

Chef::Config[:solo] = true
Chef::Config[:log_level] = :debug
Chef::Log.level(:debug)
client = Chef::Client.new
client.run_ohai
client.build_node   <-- its failing here
```

If i try to run on my shell i get following

```
[root@node1 agent]# ruby /tmp/foo.rb 
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.2/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:117:in `build_node': undefined method `reset_defaults_and_overrides' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.2/lib/chef/client.rb:259:in `build_node'
    from /tmp/foo.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I am not ruby expert so i don't know how to fix it. I just need clue what is going on

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, enough of the internal API for chef client has changed that the mcollective plugin won't work anymore. Try an older version of the chef gem.

Comment: I tried '1.8' and '1.9' also but same error, where do I get new API?

Comment: Those are Ruby versions, not Chef versions. Basically between this and your past questions, you cannot use this software. It is too broken to use without diving in to the code and you don't seem willing to do that yourself. Either hire a consultant or find another option :-/ Sorry for the harsh answer.